# Removing blank space from bottom of HTML page

Tags: html, css

I'm recreating the look of the google homepage, and I'm noticing that there is large blank area below the bottom of the body. Additionally, the page "`height`" is longer than I expected, as you need to scroll down to view the space.

This is surprising to me, because the body mainly consists of two divs set at `95%` and `5%` `height`, so I thought that would simply fill the window frame perfectly. Inspecting it with chrome tools doesn't show that any element's space taking up this extra room. I've attached a screenshot and here is the code.

```
body {
    background-color: white;
    margin:0;
}
body, html{
    height: 100%;
}

.imageTag{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom; 
}

.topItem{
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;

    margin-right: 25;
    margin-top: 13;

    opacity: .75;
}

.topItem:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.signIn{
    border:7px solid #419bf4;
    border-right: 12px solid #419bf4;
    border-left: 12px solid #419bf4;
    border-radius: 3px;

    background-color: #419bf4;

    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;

    margin-top: 8;

    opacity: 1;
}

.signIn:hover{
    cursor:pointer;

    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: #4486f7;
    border-color: #4486f7;
}

.squaresImg{
    margin-top: 8;
    margin-left: 1;
}

.squaresImg:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}

.googleImg{
    margin-top:5;
    margin-bottom:30;
}

.searchBar{
    width:550px;
    height:45px;

    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;

    background-image:url(googleMic.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 515px 10px; 
    background-size: 3%;

    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #dfdada;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);

    outline: none;

}

.searchBar:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);

}

.barItem{
    margin-right: 2;
    margin-left: 2;

    border:1px solid #eeeeee;
    padding: 9px;
    border-radius: 3px;

    background-color: #eeeeee;

    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #646464;
    font-weight: 600;

    opacity: .75;
}

.barItem:hover{

    border-color: #646464;
    color: #000000;
}   

.bottomDiv{
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 5%;*/

    background-color: #eeeeee;

    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #e4e4e4;

}

.bottomItemL{
    float: left;

    margin: 10px 15px 0;

    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
}
.bottomItemR{
    float: right;

    margin: 10px 15px 0;

    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
}

.bottomItemL:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.bottomItemR:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor:pointer;
}

 <html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Google Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div style="height: 95%">
        <div style="height: 35%">
            <span class="topItem signin" style="float: right;":>
                Sign In
            </span>
            <span style="width: 4%; height: 50%; float: right;":>
                <img class="squaresImg" src="squares.png" alt="squares">
            </span>
            <span class="topItem" style="float: right;":>
                Images
            </span>
            <span class="topItem" style="float: right;":>
                Gmail
            </span>
        </div>
        <center>        
            <img class="googleImg" src="googleLogo.png" alt="google logo">
            <div style="margin-bottom: 35">
                <input class="searchBar" type="text" name="searchBar" autofocus="autofocus">
            </div>
            <div style="height: 40%">
                <span class="barItem">Google Search</span>
                <span class="barItem">I'm Feeling Lucky</span>
            </div>              
        </center>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 5%" class="bottomDiv">
        <span class="bottomItemL" >Advertising</span>
        <span class="bottomItemL" >Business</span>
        <span class="bottomItemL" >About</span>
        <span class="bottomItemR" >Settings</span>
        <span class="bottomItemR" >Terms</span>
        <span class="bottomItemR" >Privacy</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You didn't include the link or any code. Although please don't link to jsfiddle when you can include the code in your post here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time." Just include html/css/js in your post itself using the snippet too. It's just as easy as jsfiddle.

Comment: Ignoring the padding that `jsbin` adds to the body - http://output.jsbin.com/govexotoco

Answer (score 1):

You need to define height of the parent element first, which is **body** tag.
Write this in your `<style>` tags:

```
body, html{
height: 100%;
}
body{
margin: 0
}
```

EDIT: When I checked your code, I saw nothing like that space. It's fully 100% occupied. What I saw a horizontal scroll. You can remove that.
You've provided `width: 100%` to your `bottomDiv` which is causing horizontal scroll. Just remove it, it's not necessary.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I've updated my question to include the code.

Comment: Odd. I still have it. Probably not the biggest deal - thanks for your help !

Comment: Any way, the way your code is written is not good. You should use proper `div` elements, parents and children. That will help you understand DOM better.